# error while converting from nt to rdf/xml format in Jena

Tags: jena, semantic-web, n-triples

What is the meaning of the following error message:
I am attempting to convert the dogfood.nt to its rdf/xml representation form, what does the StackOverflow message indicate ?

```
<j.12:Person rdf:about="http://data.semanticweb.org/person/rich-keller">
   <j.12:name>Rich Keller</j.12:name>
   <rdfs:label>Rich Keller</rdfs:label>
   <j.3:affiliation rdf:resource="http://data.semanticweb.org/organization/nasa-ames-research-center"/>
   <j.4:holdsRole rdf:resource="http://data.semanticweb.org/conference/iswc/2005/pc-member-at-iswc2005-research-track"/>
   </j.12:PersException in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
       at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4568)
       at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
       at java.util.regex.Pattern$BranchConn.match(Pattern.java:4568)
       at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
       at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:4272)
       at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4234)
       at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
       at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4604)
       at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
       at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4604)
       at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4602)
```

Following is the code snippet used:

```
Model model11 = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
        InputStream is1 = FileManager.get().open("dogfood4.nt");

        if (is1 != null) {
            model11.read(is1, null, "N-TRIPLE");

            model11.write(os1, "RDF/XML");
        } else {
            System.err.println("cannot read file ");;
        }
```

I am using the semantic dogfood n-triples.

Comment: Please add the code that you are running and a link to the RDF file in question.

Comment: What versions of Jena and Java are you using?

Comment: I am using jena 3.0.1 and java 8

Comment: there was a comment (on another SO question?) about a related bug i Jena 3.0.1. I don't know if it applies to your case but try another version.

Comment: it is the semantic dog food data-set,  as mentioned in the question.

Comment: @CaptSolo, any suggestions as to which version is preferred?

Comment: try 3.0.0. re. dogfood4.nt - please provide a link - otherwise we don't know what you mean by that.